# Why does this SQL work? (I don't think it should!)

Tags: sqlite

Some time ago, using SQLite, I wrote a pretty large bit of SQL as the basis of a view. Now I look at again I cannot see how it could possibly work, but its been working fine for ages.
The gist of the sql is below.
I get the **correct** value of **average(Result)** in both **x** and **y** even though **x** uses the clause...

```
select avg(result) from TableB
```

...when tableB doesn't contain a field called result.

Why doesn't this code fail?

```
CREATE TABLE TableB 
( TheKey TEXT);

 CREATE TABLE TableA 
 (  TheID TEXT,
  TheKey TEXT,
  result INTEGER  );

SELECT
    TheID,
    avg(result) as y,
    (select avg(result) from TableB as T where T.TheKey = TableA.TheKey) as x,
FROM 
    TableA
LEFT JOIN   
    TableB  
ON TableA.TheKey = TableB.TheKey
GROUP BY 
    TheID, TableA.TheKey
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a `FROM TableA LEFT JOIN TableB` both tables are in scope in the select list.

`avg(TableB.result)` would fail.

`avg(result)` is the same as `avg(TableA.result)` in this context.

Comment: Oh of course, stupid question really. I now need to make a modification that will involve using a weighting from TableB to adjust the average, thats why I spotted it. I think I probably had this mod in mind when I wrote the original SQL so I left the reference to TableB in there.